# Is it good to have unique method names across your application?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, webstorm

I might have the same method name across different and disparate objects:

```
Frame.hide = function() {
//
}
Dialog.hide = function() {
//
}
Treasure.hide = function() {
//
}
```

Is it good to keep method names across the application unique, such as:

```
Frame.hideFrame = function() {
//
}

Dialog.hideDialog = function() {
//
}
```

The best efforts of an IDE such as Webstorm, can't differentiate between the 3 hide() methods in the top snippet. As our application is growing bigger and bigger (we are at around 80 classes now), it is becoming almost impossible to navigate around code sometimes because method names are the same, and refactoring becomes downright dangerous.

Comment: Your last paragraph pretty much answered your own question. In your case, yes it seems to be good.

Comment: Unless you need the same names so that you can call `hide()` on something without knowing what it is, it seems to make sense in your case to use unique names.

Comment: you say "in my case", but shouldnt that also extend to "every case" of a JS application that is really big?

Comment: @OliverWatkins: I'd say no because other IDEs like Komodo and Visual Studio have no problems with this. So to me it's a Webstorm specific problem.

Comment: @slebetman, are you sure that if i have a method somewhere myMethod(x) { x.hide }, VS and Komodo will be able to intelligently say exactly which hide() method is being called?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a matter of taste really. I personally do not like repeating object names in the functions. 
So I favor :

```
Frame.hide = function() {}
Frame.show = function() {}
Frame.validate = function() {}
```

over:

```
Frame.hideFrame = function() {}
Frame.showFrame = function() {}
Frame.validateFrame = function() {}
```

Your IDE should never force you to do things which might not be the preferable way, in such cases you might want to search for another IDE (Netbeans?)

Comment: I understand that its not elegant to repeat object names. But elegance aside, how do you get a quick usage snapshot of the hide() method without it conflicting with the hide() method of a Dialog in your code. Does Netbeans differentiate when finding usages and refactoring?

Comment: BTW IDE is never forcing me to do anything. It is doing its best to rename a method, or find its usages, and can't seem to deal that well with JS. SOrry i am from a Java background, so refactoring, code completion, etc. is something i have always been used to.

Comment: Well, latest version of Netbeans seem to have a bug concerning find usage/refactor: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225924
It does however detect the correct class when using autocomplete of a function (e.g. Frame.hi<tab> will show Frame.hide() and its javadoc)

Comment: hmm interesting, had no idea Netbeans could do JS